# Вызов массива по множеству индексов

Tags: python

Хотел сделать массив из:

```
alphabet = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
a = alphabet[4, 10, 12, 5, 11, 6, 16, 21, 25, 13, 19, 14, 22, 24, 7, 23, 20, 18, 15, 0, 8, 1, 17, 2, 9]
print(a)
```

То есть в `output` будет записано `['E', 'K', 'F' ... 'J']`

Выводит `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Answer (score 1):

Здесь генератор нужно использовать:

```
alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
            'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
a = [alphabet[i] for i in [4, 10, 12, 5, 11, 6, 16, 21, 
                           25, 13, 19, 14, 22, 24, 7, 23, 
                           20, 18, 15, 0, 8, 1, 17, 2, 9]]
print(a)
# ['E', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'L', 'G', 'Q', 'V', 'Z', 'N', 'T', 'O', 'W', 'Y', 'H', 'X', 'U', 'S', 'P', 'A', 'I', 'B', 'R', 'C', 'J']
```

Answer (score 1):

Или через лямбда:

```
alphabet = list(map(chr, range(65, 91)))
a = list(map(lambda x: alphabet[x], [4, 10, 12, 5, 11, 6, 16, 21, 25, 13, 19, 14, 22, 24, 7, 23, 20, 18, 15, 0, 8, 1, 17, 2, 9]))
print(a)
```

Comment: Тот-же х..н в другой руке, только добавлены `lambda` и `map` которую нужно обратно распаковывать в список, вместо того, чтобы сразу сгенерить список. Это как правой пяткой левое ухо чесать, можно, но гиморойно